# EWS (Exchange Web Services) Not Recognizing All Inline Attachments

Tags: html-agility-pack, email-attachments, exchangewebservices, html-to-pdf

I have a program that connects to exchange to pull emails and then convert them to PDF. I'm having an issue with inline attachments. When I try to loop through the attachments (For Each attach As Attachment In Message.Attachments) often times it does not recoginize all of the inline images. For example, I can clearly see there are two inline attachments when I look at the email, but when I loop through, Message.Attachments count is only 1.

I've tried converting the email to html and finding all of the img tags, but I can only figure out how to save the ones whose source is a URL. SOme of the img src looks like "cid:image001.jpg@01D00953.8862B450" and I don't know how to save this in order to convert it later.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [EWSEditor](http://ewseditor.codeplex.com/) or [MFCMapi](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) to view the properties of the message and see if that helps figure out what's going on. If there's a cid tag in the body I'd expect an attachment with a matching ContentId property.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that the cid tag (cid:image001.jpg@01D00953.8862B450) was identical if the same image was used in the email (for instance, a logo as part of an email signature). When I tried to pull the emailMessage.Attachments it would only find 1 *unique* image ID and therefore saw only 1 even when I could clearly see two. Just ended up checking how many times that ID appeared in the html and reused the first image anywhere that ID was.